# Are 'more than' and 'not' interchangeable?

Tags: meaning

> And politicians, argues Michael Shellenberger, an author and activist
> who ran for governor of California in 2022, need to do **more than**
> just promise to fund the police.
>
> Many kinds of spoken language, **not** just the spontaneous speech of
> domestic conversation or discussions in pubs, have a syntax that is
> very different from the syntax of formal writing.

In the two sentences above, changing 'more than' with 'not' or 'not' with 'more than' does not change the meaning seemingly.

So,

> And politicians, argues Michael Shellenberger, an author and activist
> who ran for governor of California in 2022, need to do **not**
> just promise to fund the police.
>
> Many kinds of spoken language, **more than** just the spontaneous speech of
> domestic conversation or discussions in pubs, have a syntax that is
> very different from the syntax of formal writing.

Is there any difference here?

Comment: 1st sentence suggests that (Any politician needs to take additional actions or initiatives along with just promise to fund the police.). Using "not" here is not correct.

Comment: Here, "more" means"greater".

Comment: I think you're a bit confused: "not just" generally means "more than" or "greater than", but "not" on its own has no such connotation. However, "not just" and "more than" are not always substitutable in a sentence because they are used in different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The first example is ungrammatical with "not".  The syntax  "He needs to do not {something}..." is incorrect.  You would probably say either "He doesn't need to do something", or "He must not do something".  But those have opposite meanings, and both are different to "He needs to do more"

The second pair could have the same general meaning, because "not just {something}" implies "{something} in addition to {something}", and hence the same sense as "more than".  But the second expression is not well expressed, as it isn't clear if you intend "including more types of language" or "more particularly spoken language than other types".  The correct and clear way to express this is "... not only spontaneous speech..."

In nearly any other context "not" and "more than" have completely different meanings.  "Not happy" and "More than happy" have opposite meanings.

Comment: With "more particularly spoken language than other types", did you mean some other kinds of spoken language are more particular than '...the spontaneous speech...'?Here,'more than' has a comparative sense?

Comment: Yes, something like that.  It is not a good expression, because it isn't clear what you really want to say.